# WCF impersonation says I'm a completely different user

Tags: wcf, authentication, impersonation

I'm having a bizarre issue where I'm hitting a WCF service on a remote machine (still in same domain) and it's saying I'm logged in as someone else. On the client side, if I check the Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent(), it says I'm "COMPANYNAMEHERE\Albert". But when it goes over to the server side, it says I'm "COMPANYNAMEHERE\Albert_Admin". I've had 3 other users test the service and they authenticate fine, it's just me that has this issue.

I've had other devs log onto my machine and they're fine. I've hit other WCF services as my account with the same problem.

The IT folks are stumped, as am I. Anyone out there know what might be causing this?

Comment: Please post service and client binding & behavior configuration, together with relevant code.

Comment: Are those accounts real user accounts in your domain?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out something in my local desktop profile (I don't know what) was causing integrated security to resolve me as my _Admin account. I had tested my login on a co-worker's machine and everything worked fine. So my network admin suggested I wipe out my local profile and that seemed to do the trick.